# Multiplying Dataframe rows with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
         Date   Last  portfolioID FinancialInstrument
1   2018-03-28  64.67            1                 Oil
2   2018-03-29  64.91            1                 Oil
3   2018-04-02  62.85            1                 Oil
4   2018-04-03  63.57            1                 Oil
5   2018-04-04  63.56            1                 Oil
6   2018-04-05  63.73            1                 Oil
7   2018-04-06  61.93            1                 Oil
8   2018-03-23  65.74            3                 Oil
9   2018-03-26  65.49            3                 Oil
10  2018-03-27  64.67            3                 Oil
11  2018-03-28  64.67            3                 Oil
12  2018-03-29  64.91            3                 Oil
13  2018-04-02  62.85            3                 Oil
14  2018-04-03  63.57            3                 Oil
15  2018-04-04  63.56            3                 Oil
16  2018-04-05  63.73            3                 Oil
17  2018-04-06  61.93            3                 Oil
18  2018-04-02  62.85            5                 Oil
19  2018-04-03  63.57            5                 Oil
20  2018-04-04  63.56            5                 Oil
21  2018-04-05  63.73            5                 Oil
22  2018-04-06  61.93            5                 Oil
```

and a NumPy array that looks like this:

```
[ 152.69506795   76.05719501  127.28719173]
```

I am grouping the DataFrame using the `portfolioID` where the first grouping correlates with the first value in the NumPy array and second group with second value in the NumPy array, etc. My question is, is there a way I can multiply the `Last` column in the DataFrame with its corresponding NumPy array value?

This is what I have but I get an error stating "Length must be equal."
`shares` is the NumPy array:

```
for pid, group in data.groupby('portfolioID'):
    lastCol = group.Last
    clumN = lastCol.multiply(shares, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pandas.Series.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html) to get the indices into your value array, and use these indices to get an appropriate array to multiply by.

```
val_arr = np.array([152.69506795, 76.05719501, 127.28719173])

df.Last * val_arr[df.portfolioID.factorize()[0]]

# 1     9874.790044
# 2     9911.436861
# 3     9596.885021
# 4     9706.825470
# 5     9705.298519
# 6     9731.256680
# 7     9456.405558
# 8     5000.000000
# 9     4980.985701
# 10    4918.618801
# 11    4918.618801
# 12    4936.872528
# 13    4780.194706
# 14    4834.955887
# 15    4834.195315
# 16    4847.125038
# 17    4710.222087
# 18    8000.000000
# 19    8091.646778
# 20    8090.373906
# 21    8112.012729
# 22    7882.895784
# Name: Last, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the occurrance of each group in the df with `count` and resize the second array, `arr`, with `np.repeat`.

```
arr = np.array([152.69506795, 76.05719501, 127.28719173])
df.Last * np.repeat(arr, df.groupby("portfolioID")["Last"].count())
```